# Implement a writable serializer for multilevel nested relationships in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In drf3 you can now implement a writable nested serializer by overriding the create() method and handling validated_data yourself. However, what if you've a multi-level nested relationship in the models like so:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    """
    Order model to aggregate all the shipments created by a user at a particular time.
    """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='created at',
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='updated at',
        auto_now=True
    )

class Shipment(models.Model):
    """
    Many to One Relationship with the Orders Model. Aggregates all the details of a shipment being sent.
    """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='created at',
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='updated at',
        auto_now=True
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Order
    )

class ItemDetail(models.Model):
    """
    Specifies details of the shipment contents. One to One relationship with the Shipment Model.
    """
    shipment = models.OneToOneField(
        to=Shipment,
        primary_key=True
    )
    CONTENT_TYPES = (
        ('D', 'Documents'),
        ('P', 'Products')
    )
    content = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='package contents',
        max_length=1,
        choices=CONTENT_TYPES,
        default='P'
    )
```

How would I write a serializer for order with custom create method to handle such a case? All the examples I've seen including the one on the official page has just one level of nested relationship.

> Read is working fine with the depth argument. However, I'd really
>   appreciate any help with writing the create/update method.

Answer (score 3):

The [writable nested serializer is explained in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Please do not recreate a new serializer in the create/update.
Once you hit the top most serializer create/update, all your data are validated, including the nested ones.

At this point, you'll have to write by yourself the mapping from the validated_data to your various objects.

I tried to make it automatic for DRF 2.x but it turns out that there was too many use case, some of which were exclusives. Therefore DRF leaves that work upon the developer - i.e. you.

Comment: The documentation only shows how to write create/update for a serializer with nested depth = 1. I'm not sure how to write one for depth > 1. Will I have to write create/update on each level and it'll automatically do the validation or do I have to flatten the structure on the top serializer so the validation is done right there?

Comment: As I said in the answer, the validation is already done and includes in depths elements. You just need the top most serializer's create/update methods to create/update/delete the various instances including the one in depth, no matter how depth it is.

Comment: Gotcha. The only thing that's unclear is how would I pop the validated data for the object which is two levels down, in this case **ItemDetail**. I'm guessing the create method on the OrderSerializer would first create the order. Then the shipment and finally the ItemDetail. For shipment, I can do `shipments = validated_data.pop('shipments')`. But how would I get the validated data for ItemDetail?

Comment: shipment_data = validated_data.pop('shipments') then looping on shipment_data you'll pop the 2nd level and so on

Comment: perfect. thanks :) will try it out and post the outcome

Comment: Is it possible to write a custom serializer for a 2nd level nested object?
I have something like so:
-Assignment
 -Client
  - User
What is want is to customize the serializer for the 2nd level deep object - i.e, Customize the User Object's Serialization to include only certain fields and not all.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have two serializers, firs `ItemDetailSerializer` which will call `ShipmentSirializer` to handle `Order` and `Shipment` creation and then create `ItemDetail` itself.

Something like:

```
class ItemDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    # Describe here all relationships
    """
    class Meta:
        model = ItemDetail

    def create(self, validated_data):

        shipment = validated_data.pop('shipment')
        shipment_serializer = ShipmentSerializer(data=shipment)
        if shipment_serializer.is_valid()
            shipment_serializer.save()

            item_detail = ItemDetail.objects.create(shipment=shipment_serializer.instance,
                                                    **validated_data)
            return item_detail
```

And for the `ShipmentSerializer` you can follow documentation about nested relations, that you've mentioned.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the reply. I was actually looking for a way for defining an order serializer in which it'll make the shipments using reverse relationship (I know how to do this from the official docs). However, the part that is not clear to me is, how do I validate and create the itemdetail object while calling the order serializer?

Comment: For that you will need to implement validation yourself. Just override `validate_item_detail` method and add `item_detail` to your `OrderSerializer`

Comment: So, basically I'll have to flatten the nested structure and bring in all the child models with depth > 1 to the top serializer and create the objects in the top serializer itself? Correct me if that's not what you meant

Comment: Yes, with this approach you will need to `pop` everything with depth > 1 and  create objects for them separately.