# Writable Double-nested serializers with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, nested, django-rest-framework, writable

I have invoice with 1 or multiple `product_invoice`, and some `product_invoice` can have 1 `product_order` (so in ProductOrder, productinvoiceid shoulb be a OneToOne relashionship but it is not important for my issue).

I am able to get data on the 2 level, but I can't create, there is this error :

> TypeError: 'orderinfo' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

But if I remove `orderinfo` in `ProductInvoiceSerializer` I am able to create Invoice and related `Product_Invoice`.

What I am doing wrong ?

django : 1.9.3, DRF : 3.3.3

```
[
{
    "invoiceid": 43,
    "stocklocationid": 1,
    "invoicecode": "OBR00040",
    "invoicedate": "2016-05-07",
    "totalamount": 500000,
    "buypricetotal": 125000,
    "discount": 0,
    "ppnamount": 50000,
    "ispaid": true,
    "deposit": 0,
    "emailaddress": "",
    "customername": "",
    "invoicenote": "",
    "isorder": false,
    "deliverydate": null,
    "products": [
        {
            "productinvoiceid": 48,
            "productid": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "buyingprice": 200000,
            "saleprice": 100000,
            "orderinfo": [
                {
                    "productorderid": 2,
                    "note": "",
                    "isstock": false,
                    "stocklocationid": 1,
                    "ispickedup": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

My model :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoiceid = models.AutoField(db_column='InvoiceID', primary_key=True)
    invoicecode = models.CharField(db_column='InvoiceCode', unique=True, max_length=8)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'invoice'

class ProductInvoice(models.Model):
    productinvoiceid = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductInvoiceID', primary_key=True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ProductID')
    invoiceid = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='InvoiceID', related_name='products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity', verbose_name='Quantity')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'product_invoice'

class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    productorderid = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductOrderID', primary_key=True)
    productinvoiceid = models.ForeignKey(ProductInvoice, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ProductInvoiceID', related_name='orderinfo')
    isstock = models.BooleanField(db_column='Stock', verbose_name = 'Is stock ?')
    isreadytopick = models.IntegerField(db_column='ReadyToPick')
    ispickedup = models.IntegerField(db_column='PickedUp', verbose_name = 'Already picked-up ?')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'product_order'
```

My Serializer :

```
class ProductOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductOrder
        fields = ('productorderid','note','isstock','stocklocationid','ispickedup')

class ProductInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderinfo = ProductOrderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductInvoice
        fields = ('productinvoiceid', 'productid', 'quantity', 'buyingprice', 'saleprice', 'orderinfo')
    #fields = ('productinvoiceid', 'productid', 'quantity', 'buyingprice', 'saleprice')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ordersinfo_data = validated_data.pop('orderinfo')
        product_invoice = ProductInvoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for orderinfo_data in ordersinfo_data:
            ProductOrder.objects.create(productinvoiceid=product_invoice, **orderinfo_data)
        return product_invoice

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductInvoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('invoiceid', 'stocklocationid', 'invoicecode','invoicedate','totalamount','buypricetotal','discount','ppnamount','ispaid','deposit','emailaddress','customername','invoicenote','isorder','deliverydate','products')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        invoice = Invoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_data in products_data:
            #product_data.invoiceid = invoice.invoiceid
            ProductInvoice.objects.create(invoiceid=invoice, **product_data)
        return invoice
```

UPDATE 2016-05-11

view.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def invoice_list(request):

if request.method == 'GET':
    invoices = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoices, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, )
    return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manually creating `ProductInvoice` object here at `ProductInvoice.objects.create(invoiceid=invoice, **product_data)` and `ProductInvoice` model doesn't have any field named `orderinfo`.

Now since you are using

```
orderinfo = ProductOrderSerializer(many=True)
```

`ProductInvoice` needs to have a `ManyToMany` field to store `orderinfo`

Thus you model should be like this:

```
class ProductInvoice(models.Model):
    productinvoiceid = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductInvoiceID', primary_key=True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ProductID')
    invoiceid = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='InvoiceID', related_name='products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity', verbose_name='Quantity')
    orderinfo = models.ManyToManyField(ProductOrder)
```

**OR**

You should use `ProductInvoiceSerializer` to create `ProductInvoice` object:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        invoice = Invoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_data in products_data:
            #product_data.invoiceid = invoice.invoiceid
            data = product_data
            data['invoiceid'] = invoice
            serializer = ProductInvoiceSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
        return invoice
```

Comment: Not sure I agree with your reply. In InvoiceSerializer I am using  `products = ProductInvoiceSerializer(many=True)`, doesn't means I need a `products` field in my `Invoice` model.

Comment: @ALaplante since you are trying to create `ProductInvoice` object here `ProductInvoice.objects.create(invoiceid=invoice, **product_data)` and you are not in anyway using `ProductInvoiceSerializer`. That's why you need to either have `orderinfo` in `ProductInvoice` model or use `ProductInvoiceSerializer`. Anyway try the updated answer.

Comment: I did like your updated answer but I have this error message : `AssertionError: You cannot call '.save()' after accessing 'serializer.data'.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.`. I had the same before when I just had InvoiceSerializer and ProductInvoiceSerializer, but I fixed it by following DRF API Nested instruction. I am not sure DRF allows to call a serializer inside another serializer. Regarding your answer I just had to had `data['productid'] = product_data['productid'].pk`.

Comment: @ALaplante, can you post full code of how are you doing this? Because I can't see where are we accessing `'serializer.data'`.

Comment: Try to move object creation part from serializer to view.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no time for more try, I will back to this issue later. Meanwhile, if someone manage to do it, it will be great. The question, the way DRF is done, is it even possible to do what I am trying to do ?

Comment: There is another post with the same problem, but I can't add a comment (not enough reputation) to ask him if he figured out how to do it. [thread link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689200/implement-a-writable-serializer-for-multilevel-nested-relationships-in-django-re?answertab=active#tab-top)